# how to set endpoint for canvas.drawtext?

Tags: android, drawtext

i am trying to make an app which can write something on image but the problem is that i dont know how to finish the words or hide overflow of text that user type...if you see in image below you can see that some words go hidden because of no endpoint..i need to make an endpoint in white background

[image](https://www.dropbox.com/s/iy09gajxtou0gw5/MI_28122014_1640.png?dl=0)

this is the part of code that i used

```
//Rasme mahale bargozari rooye aks
    Paint paintMahal = new Paint();
    paintMahal.setColor(Color.BLACK);
    paintMahal.setAntiAlias(true);
    paintMahal.setTypeface(tf);
    paintMahal.setTextSize(20);


    Rect areaRect = new Rect(0, 0, 300, 100);
    Paint rec = new Paint();
    rec.setColor(Color.BLACK);

    RectF bounds = new RectF(areaRect);
    // measure text width
    bounds.right = rec.measureText(agahi, 0, agahi.length());
    // measure text height
    bounds.bottom = rec.descent() - rec.ascent();

    bounds.left =57;
    bounds.top = 374;
    canvas.drawText(agahi, bounds.left, bounds.top - rec.ascent(), rec);
    //sakhte akse karbar
```

Comment: see StaticLayout class

Comment: @pskink A layout class won't help drawing to a canvas.

Comment: @GabeSechan of course it will: see draw(Canvas) method,  TextView uses that method to draw the text

Answer (score 0):

Set a clipping region to the canvas.  The canvas can only be drawn within the clipping region, anything outside becomes a no-op.  Then remove the clipping region when done and draw as normal.